# Gunicorn and Nginx Configuration Settings

Tags: nginx, python, gunicorn, flask

I am doing some X-Ray image classification task. However, I am having trouble setting up the nginx and gunicorn configuration. I have a paperspace P4000 machine where I would like to have the webapp live.

I have to admit I am pretty much new to setting up nginx and gunicorn servers.

My `hello.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello There!!!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/flask-settings` is :

```
    server  {
             location / {
                   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                   proxy_set_header Host $host;
                   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
    }

}
```

And I am using `app.run(host=‘0.0.0.0’)` in my run.py. Right now, it’s just a simple hello world file but I would like to get the server set up right first as the DL model and code are already done.

The output of `gunicorn hello:app -b 0.0.0.0:8000` :

```
   [2257] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
   [2257] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (2257)
   [2257] [INFO] Using worker: sync
   [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 2260
```

My `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

The paperspace machine ip is 184.105.5.164 . But whenever I trying to access that it’s timing out after some time.

Looking forward to suggestions.

UPDATE :  I had to open the port `sudo ufw allow [PORT]` . It worked. Thanks to @womble

Comment: The symptom you're seeing would not be caused by any of the configuration you've provided.  Firewalling is the most likely candidate.

Comment: @womble Can you please point me to the next steps in order to figure this mess out?

Comment: @womble You were on point!! I had to open the port `sudo ufw allow [PORT]` . It worked. Thanks. :)